# What's the meaning of "save the annoyance of " something?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I was reading a book of programming language and I didn't understand the the meaning of below sentence.

The sentence is: "Navigate to File | Auto Save. This toggle will **save the annoyance of remembering** to save before rebuilding your application each time".
What does it mean by " annoyance of remembering to save "?

Can anyone describe it to me? (I will be grateful if your answer is by an example).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a programmer, but I believe it’s talking about an “Auto Save” function.

"This toggle (turn on or off) will save (spare you) the annoyance (frustration, task) of remembering to save (your progress) before rebuilding your application each time."

If you turn on the "Auto Save", your work will automatically “save” on a regular basis, meaning you won’t have to remember to do it manually – and we all forget …

An example of a "toggle" would be on your smartphone, where you can toggle things on and off in settings.